# Using an AlarmManager to check periodically that my permanent service is running

Tags: android, push-notification, android-service, alarmmanager

I have a `Service` which should keep a permanent connection to a server in order to receive notifications. It's critical for my app to get the messages from the server on time.

I cannot use GCM Push because the connection will be in the local network and the phone may not have any internet connection. I also know about the battery issues of keeping a permanent connection within a service, but I will let the user choose this option and inform him/her about the potential battery drain (Actually the feature makes mainly sense when the device is always in the same place connected to power). I also know that the Android system can kill my Service anytime, or even the user can use a task killer to get rid of all the services running at the time.

Said that, I thought about using an `AlarmManager` periodically to check whether my `Service` is running and restarting it in case it is not. I'm not convinced with this option, since the server can send a message after the service was killed but not yet restarted by the `AlarmManager`.

**My question is basically whether there are better strategies to ensure that I get the messages on time?**

So far all the related info I could find stand for avoiding the permanent service and use something else, but I have no other option because of the nature of my use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your service as a foreground service (see [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29)). Android will only kill this service in extreme situations. You can still use the alarm manager as a "safety net" to restart the service if it accidentally crashes. This is the best you can do. Nothing is 100%.

Comment: This was actually a great idea :) I think it's perfect because, thanks to the notification, the user knows that a Service is running in the background, and he/she can tap it to disable it. If Android kills the service, the user will know it as well.
Just for completeness, I can say I call `startForeground()` in the `onStartCommand()` callback. There is an example here: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/blob/master/Notifications/FakePlayer/src/com/commonsware/android/fakeplayerfg/PlayerService.java

Answer (score 2):

You could look at setting up a broadcastreceiver on any number of device broadcasts like wifi connection state and boot;

```
<receiver android:name=".receivers.BootReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name=".receivers.WifiReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Actually, this probably isn't much help. If OP has set up his service to run permanently, then `onDestroy()` will only be called if his service explicitly shuts itself down (using `stopService()` or `stopSelf()`). If Android wants to shut the service down because it needs the resources, Android will simply kill the process hosting the service, in which case `onDestroy()` will never be called.

Comment: Exactly, I already thought about that, but the method onDestroy() is not called when the Android system or the Task Manager kills the process... Additionally, the constant START_STICKY doesn't seem to be of much help neither: the Service is not started after a while of being killed...

Comment: I concur on the onDestroy stuff, it's not guaranteed or even common, removing from my answer for posterity. Thanks David.